# Angular pass variable to MatForm Component

Tags: angular, typescript

i want to pass a variable to a MatForm-Field.

I open my Component here and pass a varaible of type string, called wkn.

```
  buyItem(wkn: string, event: Event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("Buy item of this wkn: ", wkn);
    this.dialog.open(BuyItemDialogComponent, {
      data: {wkn: wkn}
    });

  }
```

and pass it to this component

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from "@angular/material/dialog";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-buy-item-dialog',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  providers: [{provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue:{} }],
  templateUrl: './buy-item-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrl: './buy-item-dialog.component.scss'
})
export class BuyItemDialogComponent {

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
    console.log('Wkn wird übergeben: ', this.data.wkn);
  }

}
```

I dont get an Error, but the value is undefined. Why?

The `console.log()` in `buyItem()` works

Comment: Why are you using this.data in the constructor? Can't you just do the console log of data?

Comment: Yes you are right i can remove this.data.

Comment: I found the mistake. I had to remove providers: [{provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue:{} }],